# Package Pingouin in colab

Tags: python, scipy, package, google-colaboratory, scipy.stats

I tried to import 'pingouin' in Colab by using standart commands:

```
!pip install pingouin
import pingouin
```

and got this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'studentized_range' from 'scipy.stats' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/**init**.py)

I tried to install 'studentized_range'
by:

```
    !pip install scipy.stats.studentized_range

from scipy.stats import studentized_range
```

and I got the same error as above.

How can I use Pinguin in Colab?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be a dependency issue. You can try uninstalling it first and install the pingouin package again:

```
!pip uninstall scipy -y
!pip uninstall pingouin -y
!pip install pingouin
```

Please acknowledge here if it works.